# Getting content from PHP: Trouble with POST and query

Tags: mysql, http, post, header, root-framework

Apologies for my longest question on SO ever. I'm trying to interface with a php frontend for a mysql database in ROOT (a CERN framework in C++ for high energy physics analysis). To start off with, I tried to get this php interface to play nice with `wget` and `curl` first because I'm more familiar with them. The following command works:

```
wget --post-data "hostname=localhost:3306&un=joeuser&pw=psswd&myquery=show_spazio_databases;" http://some.host.edu/log/log_query_matlab.php
```

The results are:

```
database1

database2
```

That's good. If I leave out the `--post-data` then I get the result:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /log/log_query_matlab.php on line 6
i'm dead! Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: NO) 
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /log/log_query_matlab.php on line 29

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /log/log_query_matlab.php on line 29
```

I have access to the php script (read only), but the error itself isn't too important. What matters it that using ROOT, I use a function called as `socket.SendRaw(message, message.Length())` (socket is a `TSocket`) and this gives me the same "error" as `wget` without the post data switch if my "message" is

```
"POST http://some.host.edu/log/log_query_matlab.php?hostname=localhost:3306&un=joeuser&pw=psswd&myquery=show_spazio_databases"
```

This may be in vain, but does someone knows a way I should format the "message" that includes something that is equivalent to the `--post-data` switch. Or, is there a standard way to format POST requests in a single line (I've seen [multi-line stuff](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#postmethod). Is that right?) Sorry I'm clueless!

PS. The mysql query is `show databases` but the space has been replaced with `_spazio_`, Italian for space. The author of the db and php interface requires it (and various replacements for symbols), but has anyone seen this before? Trying to troubleshoot that was terrible!

Comment: looks like your question is not mysql or php or header related. It can be shorted to "how to send a POST HTTP request using ROOT framework (or how to find a way to execute a commandline utility using this framework)", right?

Comment: I suppose so. It could also be "How to send a POST HTTP request in a one liner". Since ROOT is C++, maybe there is a C++ library is uses to implement SendRaw. Is there a common C++ format for submitting HTTP requests? Really, I just need to know more about HTTP requests!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct "one liner" (had to be multiline) was:

```
POST http://some.host.edu/log/log_query_matlab.php HTTP/1.1
Host: some.host.edu
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 73

hostname=localhost:3306&un=joeuser&pw=psswd&myquery=show databases
```

The end of each line has `\r\n`. The gap after content-length has two sets of those.